# Field validation for URL or IP address

Tags: angularjs, validation

Currently, I found a regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249667/4534012) which seems to do what want, and passes some tests on regex101. However that same expression does not work in angular `ng-pattern`:

This is the expression:

```
/^(http(s?):\/\/)?(((www\.)?+[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)|((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\s\.\/\?\%\#\&\=]*)$/?
.
```

which produces this error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /^(http(s?)://)?(((www.)?+[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+(.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)|((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0…){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))(/[a-zA-Z0-9_-s./?%#&=]*)?$/: Nothing to repeat
.
```

Maybe I'm getting too far ahead and dont need a regex for this. Is there something which accommodates for accepting URLs as well as IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like \ disappears, try to use double backslashes like this

```
^(http(s?):\\/\\/)?(((www\\.)?+[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)|(\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b))(\\/[a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\s\\.\\/\\?\\%\\#\\&\\=]*)?$
```

It happens due to backslash being interpreted in string as escape character.